# List Box for Aged Inventory by Days

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview

I want to filter my list box to where it only shows Items for 1-7 days, 8-14 days, a month and so on. How would I go about doing this? I am new to Qlikview but have some minor experience with coding so I figured I would use a If Then statement I am just not sure where to put it.

Comment: Possible to post data sample? (might be fake data)

Comment: Hi, has my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Usually to achieve that I am using class function. But depends on your data model it can be different:

```
Class(date, 7)
```